# WileyNJD-v2.cls is not printing the exact math equation I typed

Tags: math-mode, document-classes

```
\documentclass[AMA,STIX1COL]{WileyNJD-v2}
\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
    \dot{x}=\tilde{x}+\hat{x}
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

gives me the following pdf view[image]

Is anyone experiencing the same problem? This only happens if I use this class of document, which I must. Noticed it on October 10th.

The template for this class can be found on the link below:
https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/page/journal/14678640/homepage/custom_copy.htm

Comment: it is not a standard class, if you want someone to debug the issue can you give a link to the class you have used a

Comment: from here? https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/page/journal/14678640/homepage/custom_copy.htm

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce the issue with a minimal example:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{stix}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\dot{x}=\tilde{x}+\hat{x}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

The culprit is the `ulem` package loaded before `stix` and `amsmath`. It's not at all clear what's causing the issue, but it's certainly linked to `\dot` and the other math accent commands having become robust in the last LaTeX release (2019-10-01).

The problem is that `ulem` redefines the kernel command `\MakeRobust`.

Workaround until `ulem` is fixed:

```latex
\expandafter\def\csname ver@ulem.sty\endcsname{3000/12/31}

\documentclass[AMA,STIX1COL]{WileyNJD-v2}

% if you really need ulem
\expandafter\let\csname ver@ulem.sty\endcsname\relax
\let\kernelMakeRobust\MakeRobust
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\let\MakeRobust\kernelMakerobust

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
    \dot{x}=\tilde{x}+\hat{x}
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

### UPDATE January 2020

The release of `ulem` dated 2019-11-18 (and included in TeX Live on 2020-01-11) fixes the issue. The OP's original code now should work.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it resolved the problem in my original document as well.

Comment: Note that this workaround may change \emph function. This class was set originally to make characters italic with \emph, but is underlining instead. Fortunately, this can be encircled directly with \textit function.

Comment: @user199287 Fixed. It's hard to understand why the class loads both `ulem` and `soul`.

Comment: If I use an edited version of `ulem.sty` without the (re)definition of `\MakeRobust`, the document compiles without any intervention.

Comment: Thanks, again. The normalem option resolved. I'm not really familiar with the packages you have mentioned, so I'm in a blindspot.

Comment: @user199287 The class you're using loads a plethora of packages, using a seemingly random pattern. It seems to have been written by several people who added things without ever doing some logic reorganization.